# How to answer the "Set /p choice" command on new line?

Tags: batch-file

Code:

```
@set /p choice= How are you?(answer is here)

@echo %choice%?

@pause
```

Desired Output:

```
@set /p choice= How are you?
(answer here)
@echo %choice%?

@pause
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is very easy possible:

```
@echo off
echo How are you?
set /p "choice="
echo %choice%?
pause
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT 26/06/2015** ==> Thanks to Aacini's remark !

To echo newline (without fail) in batch you should add `echo(`

```
@echo off
echo How are you ?
::Skip two lines if you want
echo( & echo(
set /p "choice= "
echo(
echo %choice%
echo(
pause
```

Comment: Excuse me. The use of `echo.` to show empty lines (or variables) may fail under certain circumstances, so it is not convenient that a beginner get used to use it.I used `echo/`instead and the proven fail-free method is `echo(`. Further details [here](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774) or [here](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2617) or [here](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=11958).

Comment: @Aacini Thank you and i will take care about your good remark !
So, i edit my answer !